# Global refactor in Eclipse - Is that possible?

Tags: eclipse-cdt

In QT Creator, I can rename functions, variables, enums, constants etc. by using refactor. It's global refactor.

But in Eclipse, I can only rename the name of the things inside just one file.
If I want to rename a function inside a source file, then I need to manually rename it inside the header file as well. But in QT Creator, I don't need to do that. It doesn't matter if the function is included inside other header file. QT Creator will find it and rename it with the refactor function.

So my question is: Does Eclipse have that functionality as QT Creator has?